# How can I convert the unit 'GeV/G' to 'GeV'?

Tags: electromagnetism, unit-conversion

I found it here:
I think it is the first adiabatic invariant but,
How can I convert 'M [GeV/G]' to GeV?
Maybe GeV divided by the gauss of the magnetic field strenght that the proton is experiencing?
And what is K=0.01?

[image]

Source (figure 5): https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1258 ([RG](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269116641_TRAPPED_proton_fluxes_at_low_earth_orbits_measured_by_the_PAMELA_experiment))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the text of the paper,

> The motion of trapped particles was assumed to be a superposition of three periodic motions: a gyration around the local magnetic field lines, a bouncing along field lines between conjugate mirror points in the northern and southern magnetic hemispheres, and a drift around the Earth. Each type of motion is related to an adiabatic invariant, which is conserved under the condition of small magnetic field variations during the period of the motion, and in absence of energy loss, nuclear scattering and radial diffusion.

And from the caption to your selected figure,

> Stably-trapped differential flux ($\rm GeV^{−1}m^{−2}s^{−1}sr^{−1}$) at geomagnetic equator compared with a theoretical calculation by Selesnick et al. (2007) for the year 2000. Spectra are reported as a function of the first adiabatic invariant $M$ for sample values of $K$ and $L^*$ invariants.

Equations 6–9 make clear that $M = \frac{p^2/2m_0}{B_m}$ is the kinetic energy divided by the magnetic field *at the point where the particle is reflected*, while $K = \int \mathrm ds \sqrt{B_m - B(s)}$ has to do with the difference between the maximal/reflecting magnetic field and the magnetic field elsewhere along the trajectory, and $L^*$ has to do with the ion’s equatorial drift motion around the Earth.

What’s happening here, and the mechanism by which radiation becomes trapped in the van Allen belts in the first place, is a phenomenon that was called a “magnetic mirror” when I learned about it (but which doesn’t seem to have good online representation under that name).  In a *uniform* magnetic field, a charged particle travels in a helix whose axis is parallel to the magnetic field: the perpendicular part of the momentum sets the radius of gyration, and the parallel part of the momentum sets the drift velocity.  In a magnetic field whose strength changes slowly (adiabatically, in the jargon), such a particle will have different behaviors depending on whether it’s heading towards the weaker or the stronger part of the field.  A particle which moves from a strong-field region to a weak-field region will see its “perpendicular kinetic energy” $p_\perp^2/2m$ converted into “parallel kinetic energy” $p_\parallel^2/2m$: the magnetic field doesn’t do any work on the particle, but moving to a weak-field region does un-helix the particle’s motion.  By contrast a particle heading towards the strong-field region will see its “parallel kinetic energy” $p_\parallel^2/2m$ decreased compared to its “perpendicular energy” $p_\perp^2/2m$.  A sufficiently-strong magnetic field may repel some charged particles entirely, by making their momentum entirely helical before they have reached the field maximum.  This is the “mirror” part, and it’s why charged particles in the van Allen belts bounce back and forth between the poles instead of crashing into the atmosphere.

If I had to guess about converting your plot back into energy, in a hurry, for an exam or something, I’d do it as follows:

- The invariant $L^*$, which has units of length, might correspond to the distance between the particle’s center of gyration and the Earth’s axis of rotation in the plane of Earth’s equator, if you make some not-quite-correct assumptions about Earth being an ideal magnetic dipole.  Your plot only shows a subset of data with one particular $L^* = 1.16\,R_\text{Earth}$.
- For a field line passing through a particular altitude, with those same ideal-dipole assumptions, the choice of $K = 0.01\,\text{gauss}^{1/2} R_\text{Earth}$, in conjunction with the previous choice for $L^*$, probably corresponds to a reflecting field at particular latitude, which a person might be able to figure out by doing the integral which defines $K$.
- Having used $K$ to find the reflecting field $B_m$, you can then take the product $B_m M$ to find the kinetic energy of the particles in each bin in your spectrum.

I would also expect, while going through this recipe, to discover that it’s wrong in some sneaky way. The text does warn that “the adiabatic invariants cannot be treated as spatial coordinates since they are properties of the particles”; that sounds like a sad chapter in somebody’s PhD thesis.

Comment: thanks, so I have to multiply let's say 1 Gev/G by the magnetic field in gauss or tesla?

Comment: Yes, but figuring out *which* magnetic field is going to take some work on your part.

Comment: well i actually realized I had a graph with the stably-trapped protons flux, but thanks a lot!